# Disable GameObject creation when clicking on a GUI Button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a chunk of code similar to this:

```
GameObject prefab; // Gets set when GUI button is clicked

void Update(){
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && prefab){
        Instantiate(prefab, /* At mouse position on ground */);
        prefab = null;
    }
}
```

Here is the code when I click the button:

```
public void SetBuilding(GameObject building){
    prefab = building;
    Destroy(ghostBuildingObject);
    ghostBuildingObject = Instantiate(building);

    if (ghostBuildingObject) {
        // Set the alpha to half
        Color c = ghostBuildingObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;
        c.a = 0.5f;
        ghostBuildingObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = c;

        // Disable Components
        ghostBuildingObject.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = true;
        Destroy(ghostBuildingObject.GetComponent<NavMeshObstacle>());
        Destroy(ghostBuildingObject.GetComponent<Building>());
        ghostBuilding = ghostBuildingObject.AddComponent<GhostBuilding>();
        ghostBuildingObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ghost");
        ghostBuildingObject.name = "Ghost Building";
    }
}
```

Basically what it does is creates an object where I click on the ground object. What happens is when I click on a button it still creates the game object. How can I stop it from creating a gameObject when I click on a GUI Button?

Comment: What type of button are you using? Are you using the `Image` component as a button or the `Button` component as a button? Also, post the button code that will be helpful in fixing your code..

Comment: I am using a Button (`UnityEngine.GUI.Button`).

Comment: Why don't you use the new unity5 GUI elements? Anyway, the solution is to use a bool like this.

1- Make a raycast check to test that you don't hit anything just inside if your input check
2- If raycast == false -> then you can create the object.
3- else not 

let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: I am using the unity5 GUI elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was in the process of typing this before you put your own answer. I still decided to put my answer because what you did in  your answer is so wrong and unnecessary. You are **allocating** memory **multiple** times per frame, in the code in your answer only to detect a click...

> I am using a Button (UnityEngine.GUI.Button)
>
> I am using the unity5 GUI elements

You shouldn't be using that to begin with. Some people suggests you should use a raycast but the problem of a ray passing through a UI will still remain.

What you need is the a `Button` from `UnityEngine.UI.Button` not `UnityEngine.GUI.Button`. You have to change your whole program to use `UI` from `UnityEngine.UI`.

To create your button, you go to **GameObject**->**UI**->**Button**. That should create Canvas and other components required to get Button to work. Here are  Unity UI [tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

> Basically what it does is creates an object where I click on the
>   ground object.

You can detect a button click by implementing `IPointerClickHandler` and overriding the `OnPointerClick` function.

Attach the script below to the ground you want to detect the click.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{

    void Start()
    {
        Camera.main.gameObject.AddComponent<PhysicsRaycaster>();
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked!");
    }
}
```

For your Button, you can just subscribe to to Buttons using the `Button.onClick.AddListener(() => functionName());`. Below is a full code for detecting clicks on 3 buttons. The good thing about this is that only one click will be detected. Clicks will not go through other GameObjects and you are **NOT** allocating memory each frame just to detect a button click.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Button button1;
    public Button button2;
    public Button button3;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        //Register Button Events
        button1.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button1));
        button2.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button2));
        button3.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button3));

    }

    private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
    {
        if (buttonPressed == button1)
        {
            //Your code for button 1
            //Call your SetBuilding(GameObject building) function for any button
            SetBuilding(someGameOBject);
        }

        if (buttonPressed == button2)
        {
            //Your code for button 2
        }

        if (buttonPressed == button3)
        {
            //Your code for button 3
        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Register Button Events
        button1.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        button2.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        button3.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant `UnityEngine.UI.Button`, sorry I had a typeo

Comment: I think you're missing the issue. Think of a city building game, where you click on an item you want to build from the UI, then you click on the map to place that building. I am doing the same thing, but what is happening is when you click on the UI button, it selects the building then instantly places it on the map.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Didn't know it was a typo because `UnityEngine.GUI.Button` is also valid. What you have in your answer is bizarre and not good. Creating a new list for each frame is awful. My answer is still valid for you if you want to fix it. You said you are doing the-same thing as me. That's not true.

Comment: You are using `Input.GetMouseButtonUp` which will always be called when mouse is clicked even if the UI button is clicked. Mine will not detect click on your object if UI button caught the click. That is the problem you are having. My solution shows you the right way to detect click on an object. Yo can take it and apply it to what you are doing. If your solution works for you and you are fine with the memory allocation then stick with it.

Comment: I can not attach that first script to the ground, it is not a UI element. The script(s) need to be able to click on a button then click on the ground.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn You down-voted answer without even trying it. I know that the ground is **not** a `UI`. The first code should detect touch on a **mesh** too.It should. That's why I added `PhysicsRaycaster` to the camera in the `Start()` function.  Now, next time before complaining about an answer, make sure to try it. It's one thing to try something and say it doesn't work. It is another thing to complain when didn't even try it. The `IPointerClickHandler` is meant to prevent the problem you are having. Again, you don't have to use it but it is crazy to downvote something you didn't try.

Comment: I did try it and it doesn't work. OnPointerClick is for UI items

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Please stop saying that  `OnPointerClick` is for UI items. This will confuse newbies out there. It works on my side. I think this is a new future from 4.6, and that is the commended way of detecting click on a gameobject. Forget about using raycast to detect click. raycast should be used for other things but not for a click anymore.   Simply attach the first code in my answer to the ground GameObject you want to detect the click on. Make sure that there is a collider on the floor and it is not trigger. Click on it and you should see "Clicked" on the console.

Comment: If that doesn't work, just create a project scene with a floor and attach the script that you said does not work then upload it here. I show you where you messed up. `OnPointerClick` was designed for both UI and anything with collider. It came with `PhysicsRaycaster` and `Physics2DRaycaster` for camera.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I will test mesh collider and let you know.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes, it took me 5 seconds to test that. It works with mesh collider. It should work with all other colliders. upload a simple project that is not your main project and I will see what's wrong with it. Note that it won't work if you don't implement `IPointerClickHandler`

Comment: I got it! I had to edit the event mask on the Raycaster from `Everything` to `Ground`. If you edit your answer I can change the vote.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Good. I think you messed with your layers somehow. You usually don't have to change the layer to make it work. It should work automatically. In the future, avoid using raycast to detect clicks even on sprites. If you are doing this on a `Sprite`, simply replace `PhysicsRaycaster` with `Physics2DRaycaster` and that should work too. Also before you dislike answer,try it, then tell the person it doesn't work. Maybe you are doing something wrong and he/she can help further. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i clearly understand but you are Instantiating on the button and at the click:

```
ghostBuildingObject = Instantiate(building);
```

and

```
Instantiate(prefab, /* At mouse position on ground */);
```

so it's normal for it to be created 2 times

Comment: It is only getting created once. I don't want it to be created at all. The "Ghost Build" is an item that displays where the prefab will be placed once it is clicked on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && prefab != null){
    Instantiate(prefab, /* At mouse position on ground */);
    prefab = null;
}
```

Comment: `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && prefab != null` is the-same as `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && prefab` in Unity because there is an operator overload for every Object that makes them return true if not null.

Answer (score -1):

Using Pointer Events seems to fix the issue:

```
void Update(){
    // Get pointer events
    var pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
    pointer.position = Input.mousePosition;

    // Test the raycast
    List<RaycastResult> raycastResults = new List<RaycastResult>();
    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResults);

    // Check if anything was cast
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && raycastResults.Count == 0 && prefab){
        Instantiate(prefab, /* At mouse position on ground */);
        prefab = null;
    }
}
```